# Print the length of an array passed by reference in php

Tags: php

How can I print the length of an array passed by reference in php. The variable that I will get is a reference variable. So how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as printing the length of an array passed by value:

```
function print_count(&$array){
    echo count($array);
}
```

> References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by
>   different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you
>   cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual
>   memory addresses, and so on. Instead, they are symbol table aliases. Note that in PHP,
>   variable name and variable content are different, so the same content
>   can have different names.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it works the same:

```
$arr = array('hi');
$arr2 = &$arr;

var_dump(count($arr2));
```